# How can I create a nested IF without ELSE in Business Central AL

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I would like to have a nested `if` without an inner `else` but I do want to have an outer `else` branch.

See the following procedure as an example:

```
procedure GetRelatedInvoiceHeader(SalesCrMemoHeader: Record "Sales Cr.Memo Header") SalesInvHeader: Record "Sales Invoice Header"
var
    CancelledDocument: Record "Cancelled Document";
    Temp: Decimal;
begin
    SalesCrMemoHeader.CalcFields(SalesCrMemoHeader.Corrective, SalesCrMemoHeader.Cancelled);
    if SalesCrMemoHeader.Corrective then
        if CancelledDocument.FindSalesCorrectiveCrMemo(SalesCrMemoHeader."No.") then
            SalesInvHeader.Get(CancelledDocument."Cancelled Doc. No.")
        else
            Temp := 0
    else
        if CancelledDocument.FindSalesCancelledCrMemo(SalesCrMemoHeader."No.") then
            SalesInvHeader.Get(CancelledDocument."Cancelled Doc. No.");
end;
```

The `else Temp := 0` was only inserted to make the compiler happy. If the inner `else` is omitted, the AL compiler interprets the outer `else` as the inner `else`.

I tried semicolons and wrapped around begin .. end everywhere but it appears to me that what I want is not possible.

Is there a way to have only an outer `else` branch in a nested conditional statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrapping the outer** (first) **if statement in a begin end block** seems to be working for me:

```
procedure GetRelatedInvoiceHeader(SalesCrMemoHeader: Record "Sales Cr.Memo Header") SalesInvHeader: Record "Sales Invoice Header"
    var
        CancelledDocument: Record "Cancelled Document";
    begin
        SalesCrMemoHeader.CalcFields(SalesCrMemoHeader.Corrective, SalesCrMemoHeader.Cancelled);
        if SalesCrMemoHeader.Corrective then begin
            if CancelledDocument.FindSalesCorrectiveCrMemo(SalesCrMemoHeader."No.") then
                SalesInvHeader.Get(CancelledDocument."Cancelled Doc. No.")
        end else
            if CancelledDocument.FindSalesCancelledCrMemo(SalesCrMemoHeader."No.") then
                SalesInvHeader.Get(CancelledDocument."Cancelled Doc. No.");
    end;
```

The code written like this doesn't even show the usual CodeCop [AL(AA0005)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/analyzers/codecop-aa0005) warning (*Only use BEGIN..END to enclose compound statements*).
It seems like there was no major oversight by the AL development team here after all.

Comment: The rule is working as intended. The situation is mentioned in [code guidelines](https://alguidelines.dev/docs/navpatterns/3-cal-coding-guidelines/readability/begin-end/) as an exception from the AA0005 rule.